# Images half the size after packaging in Phonegap and opening on WP7

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have a series of images lined up using the following code.

HTML for each image is something like...

```
    <div class="hover panel">
    <div class="front">
        <img src="breeds/Bluefaced_Leicester.jpg" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS is ...

```
    .panel {
        float: left;
        width: 220px;
        height: 220px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 7px;
        position: relative;
        font-size: .8em;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    }
    .panel img {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Here is what it looks like when I preview it on 480x800 web windows...

[image]

Here is what it looks like on the WP7 Emulator...

[image]

How can I ensure the images show up as 220px on the WP7?

Comment: tried setting the `img width="220"` attr?

Comment: Are you sure all the images are of same size?

Comment: Have you tried setting `.panel img` to `display: block;`?

Comment: 1. tried width="220" doesn't fix 2. Images are same width different height 3. Not sure how display: block would change the pixel size but might give it a try later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to double the pixel size of all elements within the applications. Not the best solution but it works.